# Window.show not loading contents in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to bring up a window as a loading screen using the system.windows.window.show() method. The program is supposed continue running code and then close the window after it is done. The problem is that the window will not show the textblock I am trying to display. But when I do ShowDialog() it will

```
LoadingWindow lw = new LoadingWindow();
lw.Show();

//
//do stuff
//

lw.Close();
```

```
<Window x:Class="RevitAPITest3.LoadingWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RevitAPITest3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Loading..." Height="450" Width="800"  >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="text" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="291">testing</TextBlock>



    </Grid>

    
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a fundamental difference between `lw.Show()` and `lw.ShowDialog()`.

- `lw.Show()` will immediately return to the next line of code without waiting for the window to close.
- `lw.ShowDialog()` will wait for the window to close manually by the user, then return a value of true/false.

In your example code, your problem is that because `lw.Show()` returns immediately, it will then "do stuff" and then call `lw.Close()` which closes your window before you even see the window.

What you'll want to do is something like this. **Notice:** You never have to explicitly call `lw.Close()` because the window will automatically be closed as soon as it completes the `lw.ShowDialog()` line.

```
var result = lw.ShowDialog();

if (result.HasValue)
{
    //
    //do Stuff
    //
}
```

Comment: I understand the difference between them but the problem is when I do that the user has to manually close the window. I would like it to close automatically when the program is finished doing the background stuff, like a loading screen

Comment: Oh I see. In that case, I'm suspecting that your `lw` window just isn't on top (or your "do stuff" is just too fast). Try setting its `lw.TopMost`property to True before you show it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. TopMost did not work and I tried doing it with some tasks which take longer (over a minute) and the content still did not load. The window appears but it is just blank.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear to me in your initial post that you could SEE the window, but not the contents that it was supposed to contain.  Could you share the `lw` window's xaml and code-behind?  That could shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I added the xaml. I tried to use async await to run it in parallel but that didn't work since it is a wpf. I will try using either a thread or background worker and see if that fixes it

Comment: @RossLamon, see my 2nd answer.  It's a complete solution which I've tested to work.  Not sure what else you may be doing that might be messing it up, but maybe you can use my sample as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working solution.  Check to see where you are doing things differently and see if you can match this implementation.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="LoadingWindowTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Main Window" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace LoadingWindowTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private LoadingWindow lw;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Make the main window hidden until loading is done
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            // Show the Loading window
            lw = new LoadingWindow();
            lw.Show();

            // Simulate a long running task
            await Task.Delay(5000);

            // Close the Loading window
            lw.Close();

            // Show the Main Window
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

**LoadingWindow.xaml (no xaml.cs shared because I didn't touch it)**

```
<Window x:Class="LoadingWindowTest.LoadingWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="LoadingWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="text" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="291">testing</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Build and Run, then this is the Expected Output:**

You should see the LoadingWindow on the center of the screen, then after 5 seconds, it closes and the MainWindow shows.

Comment: Ok, I found another version of this question and it gave a similar answer. Since I am trying to modify the listbox which will be subsequently shown in the next window it gave me an error since another thread owns it. To get around this I used a dispatcher and I think it is stopping it from running in parallel. I am starting to think this is possibly not a threading problem. Honestly drawing blanks here. I even tried it with a background worker

Comment: Try using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke instead of Dispatcher.Invoke if you haven't done so already.  If that doesn't solve your problem, you will need to provide more code in order for us to see where the problem lies, or provide a minimal reproducible sample of your problem isolated.